# What is a person who participates in computer network chatting, called?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, terminology

I just wrote the word “chatter”, but then, googling it, I found no definition in the direction of “one who participates in a computer based chat”. Can the role of such a person be called a “chatter”? If not, then what?

Example usage:

> With a Turing test anything that would place the computer at even more of a disadvantage than it already is, is strictly forbidden. Hence the text only chat communication with the skeptics/critics/judges (whatever). One doesn’t want an observant skeptic  noting, say, that one **chatter** is metallic with a lot of electric wires, while the other one looks and sounds very much like a human female, has a glass of water at her side, and even wears a nice perfume.

Comment: Aren't they all *subjects*? I.e., *test* subjects that are being evaluated.

Comment: *Chatter* is taken -- it has both colloquial as well as technical usage -- so it is not an option at all.

Comment: Given that the Turing Test long antedates the modern chat room, I am impelled to ask what word Turing himself used. "Interlocutor" probably.  But this affects only the (IMO) rather dumb quote, not the OP's question. (Rather dumb because the original Turing Test involved pretending to be the opposite gender, so the human female with a nice perfume would be a no-go anyway.)

Comment: @DavidPugh: Turing used the words “player”.and “interrogator” in [the Turing test paper](http://www.csee.umbc.edu/courses/471/papers/turing.pdf). His terminology was evidently influenced by WWII.

Comment: Just reading the title, I thought of *texter*. If you think that *email* is a word now, it may be time for *echat*, thus an ***echatter***.

Answer (score 8):

The old school way is to refer to them as "**chat users**" or "chat room users"

> Google provides the proof
>
> "chat user"  411,000 results
>   "chat member" 235,000 results

"Please follow the rules when communicating with other chat room users."

If you google users with "chat room"  , you will find 7,000,000 results.  The first results will show popular companies referring to "chat room users" on their websites.

Comment: This is well worth knowing. But for the specific use case in the question I think the persons/entitites participating in the test are not "users". Or?

Comment: Yes, persons or entities using a computer are called "users" by definition.

Comment: it's a good point that "chat room users" is common.  nice work.

Comment: Just to add, for me, it is not a stretch to think of an "AI user."  Since it is just another "intelligence" logged in as a "user".

Answer (score 7):

My take is the proper and correct word is *chatter*, and that any ambiguity created by other, parallel, meanings of that word will be resolved by context, just like everything else.

Having said that, if you're really in need of an alternative, you may consider ***interlocutor***.

From [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/interlocutor):

> ***interlocutor***: a person who takes part in a conversation.

And again from [Wikipedia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interlocutor_(linguistics)):

> In linguistics, discourse analysis, and related fields **an *interlocutor* is a person involved in a conversation or dialogue**.

**Edit**: Just noticed @DavidPugh [previously suggested this in the comments under the question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/249225/what-is-a-person-who-participates-in-computer-network-chatting-called#comment541514_249225). Credit where it's due!

Comment: Just wanted to throw in my vociferous agreement that interlocutor is probably the most precise and appropriate term for this asker's example.

Answer (score 5):

In common sense 'chat users' is the way to go - going vice versa , few foreign languages I know all use a local analog of it .
In the Turing test case though, as it is more of an experiment I'd say 'participant' .

Comment: +1 for *participant*, though it needs context to introduce it. *User* on its own would also work given context.

Comment: 'chat participant', then (@ChrisH)

Answer (score 2):

I think that a common definition is:

> - ***chat member***

From *The Internet Encyclopedia*:

> - This type of implementation tends to be significantly slower at distributing messages to [chat members](https://books.google.it/books?id=ACfBmYiNaTcC&pg=PA667&dq=%22chat%20members%22&hl=it&sa=X&ei=QfVnVf6mMqLC7gbO2IDwDA&ved=0CEwQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=%22chat%20members%22&f=false).

From *Writing and Digital Media*

> - IC contributions are usually sent to the server for distribution to the other [chat members](https://books.google.it/books?id=mUr0AgAAQBAJ&pg=PA66&dq=%22chat%20members%22&hl=it&sa=X&ei=QfVnVf6mMqLC7gbO2IDwDA&ved=0CFsQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=%22chat%20members%22&f=false) only when the writer presses the RETURN key to dispatch what is usually a line of text, though in some systems like Hotline the limit may be as much as ...

From www.computerworld.com:

> - Anonymous [member](http://www.computerworld.com/article/2492516/cybercrime-hacking/anonymous-member-arrested-during-online-chat-after-threat-against-fbi.html) 
>     arrested during online chat after threat against FBI

Comment: you know, I'd probably just say a "chat participant".  "member" makes me thing more of "have an account"/

Comment: @JoeBlow - to participate in a chat you must be registered somehow, and be a member of the chat: http://www.ning.com/help/?p=905

Comment: (1) that's my point.  you can be registered as a user or whatever, but not actually "in the chat room".  (2) note that you do not, at all, in many way, have to be registered to participate in many chats, these days.  very often you just click to bring up a chat box, with no registration or membership required

Comment: @JoeBlow - we are all registered one way or the other, and referring to regular, popular chat rooms, *member* is a term commonly  used.http://www.computerworld.com/article/2492516/cybercrime-hacking/anonymous-member-arrested-during-online-chat-after-threat-against-fbi.html

Comment: @Josh61 "Anonymous member" means a member of *Anonymous*, the hacking psuedo-group.  "Member" is not referring to being part of the chat.  Further, you can be a member of a chat and in the chatroom without doing any chatting yourself.

Answer (score 0):

On IRC, one of the oldest chat networks, participants in a chat were simply called : "user".

Comment: Yeah but this was in the generic sense, and it only works when the context is clear: the context of being in a chat room. I guess this question is: "what is the specific word for users where users are users of a chat system?"

Answer (score 0):

"mudders" or "spods"

A mid-80's technology that is the ancestor to both modern MMORPGs and to what we know as internet chat today was the old Telnet client "multiple user dungeons" or "multiple user domains", called MUDs.  Users were called "mudders", and chat-only MUDs with game elements removed, known as "talkers", had users called "spods"

http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/spod

spod (plural spods)
1.(Internet) one who uses talkers

http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/talker

talker (plural talkers)
...
5.(Internet) A stripped-down version of a MUD which is designed for talking, that predates instant messengers; a kind of early chat room.

Comment: That's very arcane jargon for what a subset of them (MUD users) used to be called, 30 years ago. It doesn't answer the question of what they are (generically) called, today.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers cover the most appropriate terms, but I'd like to add one more option:

Since your question seeks to describe participants in a Turing test, you might call these participants *test candidates*, or just *candidates* (in other words, they are "competing" for candidacy of the status of "most humanlike" in the eyes of the test administrators).

Answer (score 0):

Since you've already used "person" and "participant" in the question itself, you're obviously looking for more specific terms. *Chatter* in the sense of "one who chats" is not defined in any dictionary I have found. As already mentioned, an ***interlocutor*** is "a person who takes part in a conversation or dialogue." This is accurate, but it's a five-syllable mouthful. "Conversationalist" and "dialogist" are equally accurate but cumbersome. "Talker" and "Speaker" are only two syllables each, but the idea of chatting back and forth is lost.

To discover or create a more specific term for “one who participates in a computer based chat” it may be helpful to specifically define "computer based chat" or give it a richer context.

***Services*** such as AIM, Skype, Facebook Chat and Hangouts havse *uers*.
***Chat rooms*** and ***forums***, usually classify their users as *moderators*, *members*, and *guests*, indicating role permissions in the environment.
***Meetings*** (online or otherwise) typically have one or more *hosts*, *presenters*,*speakers*, *participants*, *attendees*, *listeners*, or *observers*. Similarly, a ***talk show*** usually has a *host*, *staff*, *guests*, and an *audience*.

So many terms, but none of them unambiguously referring to *chat users*. I'm not sure there is a one-word solution without supporting context.